# comparing two tables from sysobjects and syscolumns but its hanging

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am trying to run this query :

> select o.name from sysobjects o, syscolumns s where
>    o.name='FFF_md' and s.name not in (select s.name from sysobjects o, syscolumns s where o.name='FFF' and o.id=s.id) and o.id=s.id

But its not giving me any results , it just haging and the only way to close ASE is by task manager.

 why I am doing this query ? I am comparing 2 tables which have alot of commun columns, I want to know what are the columns that not in commun.

I had my results in another way, and it is by tem tables .I created 2 temp tables and then i compared them.

Comment: If you want to get columns that not exists in second table your query works for me

Comment: then why I am facing such issue @Parado

Comment: I don't know why, can you describe your tables FFF and FFF_md?